# Making a transparent pixel color to white in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, pixel

I am saving a PNG in photoshop with a transparent background.

When I export the image as PNG, each pixel of the "transparent" part has an alpha value of 0, but in the program that I am using (game development) even if the alpha is 0, I need to assign the RGB of the pixels. so a transparency pixel should have an RGBA value of ( 255,255,255,0).

Photoshop automatically assumes that transparency has the same RGB value as the edges of the images. For the requirements of the work, I need the pixels of the work to be white even if they have alpha 0 (They are transparent with 0% opacity). So the transparent pixels need to have an RGBA value of (0,0,0,0).

How I can make this?

I can change the format of the file or even use another tool. How can I do this?

Comment: _transparency has the same color as the edges of the images_: what do you mean with that?

Comment: if it's PNG-8, does this answer your question? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/photoshop-how-to-use-a-non-white-background-as-the-basis-for-semitransparent-la?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question either - I have the same question as @Luciano. What does "transparency has the same colour as the edges" mean?  Can you please edit your question to clarify, and perhaps consider sharing the image file, or show what has failed. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I will update my question in order to be more precise